# Security warning in browser

Tags: browser, security

If you visit the URL below, your browser would give you a warning regarding site security. What is the cause of the warning?

What can I do to prevent other people from seeing this warning?

Here is the website link:

https://training.vlmservice.com

Please explain !

Comment: Did you see the answer below? Was it helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are talking about the warning that the page contains both secured and not secured elements please ensure you access all resources using HTTPS.